# Eclipse PDE - ViewPart onExit command?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an issue with a view that showed a Tree that made a lot of connections to a SQLite database, and want to make just one instead.
I therefore need to use something that controls its lifecycle, so that the connection would be opened and closed together with the view.

So I looked [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ViewPart.html) and I looked directly at the methods that it had, but can't find nothing with **exit**. I did have the constructor I could overwrite instead of an init method...

P.S. Am I thinking about this wrong? Should the connection be opened and closed differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further inspection I've spotted in the [exact link I shared](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ViewPart.html) this:

> Subclasses may extend or reimplement the following methods as
>   required:
>
> - setInitializationData - extend to provide additional initialization
>     when view extension is instantiated
> - init(IWorkbenchPartSite) - extend
>     to provide additional initialization when view is assigned its site
> - dispose - extend to provide additional cleanup
> - getAdapter -
>     reimplement to make their view adaptable

So yeah: **dispose()** is the answer. I'm still getting used to the naming conventions here.

Anyway, I hope this is useful to somebody except me :)